# Can I use a Microsoft Word file as a report template for JasperReports?

Tags: ms-word, jasper-reports

I have several model contracts in Microsoft Word files with as many as 20 pages per file). I would like to use Jasper Reports to fill out these contracts.

I tried importing the doc file into iReport, but that is not working.

Is there a way to convert a Microsoft Word file to a JasperReport template?

Comment: Is there any particular reason for introducing Jasper into the equation? You can fill the Word documents (preserving their formatting) using various techniques eg merge fields, custom xml data binding... Is Java your preferred language?

Comment: hi @khadher, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Try to convert the doc into excel and than use the excel as datasource in ireport.

**Edit**: Based on OP's comment.

You can not use a Microsoft word file as a JasperReport template. You will need to create a JRXML file for JasperReports. It is possible to use rtf or html as source for text fields but the final formating of such field is rather pure.

Your other option is to not user JasperReports and manipulate the Microsoft Word files directly using [Apache Poi](http://poi.apache.org/).

Comment: if I convert the document to excel I risk losing the Word template

Comment: but you can not use word as jasper report template, You will have to create jrxml (jasper) file for jasper reports. There is some way how to use rtf or html as source for text fields but the final formating of such field is rather pure. I you want to use msword documents you can use http://poi.apache.org/ to manipulate it.

Comment: @Josef I edited your answer based on your comment (since that answered the OP's question)

Comment: yes i see your answer. thank you. but i still searching a solution for my problem. i find something that i think it can be a solution. it's FreeMarker with RtfTemplate. But i don't find how to install this to jasper.

Comment: I had to use jasper for contracts creation , I have a lot of ms word templates and I was searching for the same solution like you, but with no result. So I have created all jasper reports from scratch at the end :-)

Comment: at the end it was worth it, but today I would had use some different solution (poi etc..) , creating nice looking (text) documents with jasper is painfull. If there is only few fields you need replace with jasper and they have standardized length you can try to convert yours docs to svg image and use that image as report background. But I don't know if it is possible to create nice svg from ms word.

Comment: thank you for answer. but it's not the best solution. because when i'll convert my model to image i'll lost my text. it meens that when i create my final report when i'll export it to rtf i'll never get the original text it'll be an image. and i want to have allways my original text if i'll change something it'll be asy to do.

Comment: hi @JosefProcházka, do you found any solution for this case?